# NSDateFormatter and NSDateComponents return different values for the week number

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I'm making an app that creates a timetable. You can create a new one every week of the year. When the app has finished loading, it needs to load up the current week (For example: If it's the 1st of January, week 1 needs to be shown). I use NSDateFormatter to determine what the current week is.

**NSDateFormatter**

(I was testing this on the 9th of August 2016)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ww"];

int currentWeek = [[time stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];
```

I wanted to check if it was working so I used NSLog.

```
NSLog(@"%i", currentWeek);
```

It returned `32`.

**NSDateComponents**

So NSDateFormatter thinks the current week is `32`. So far, so good. The app needs to send a push notification to tell the user that a certain period is about to begin. So the app schedules a notification using NSDateComponents.

```
// Setting the notification's fire date.
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setWeekday:3];  // Because it's on a Tuesday
[dateComps setWeekOfYear:currentWeek];  // 32
[dateComps setYear:2016];
[dateComps setHour:12];
[dateComps setMinute:20];
NSDate *theFireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

// Creates the notification.
UILocalNotification *Alert = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
Alert.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
Alert.alertBody = @"This is a message!";
Alert.fireDate = theFireDate;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:Alert];
```

And I also used NSLog.

```
NSLog(@"%@", theFireDate);
```

But it returned `2016-08-02 12:20:00 +0000` which is not the current date. It actually is the current date minus 7 days, or one week earlier. So does this mean that the current week is actually `33` instead of `32`, which means NSDateFormatter is wrong? Or is it actually `32` which means NSDateComponents is wrong. And what causes the difference between those two?

Comment: Try to set locale and timezone to date formatter and then debug again.

Comment: Don't ask me why, but with `NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]`, it works (I have a Gregorian one), but with your alloc/init of it, I encounter the same issue. Seems to be missing a setting somewhere. If I set `[calendar setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];`, it works.

Comment: I agree, it looks like you have a mismatch between timezone, locale and calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `NSDateFormatter`, use `NSCalendar` which is much more accurate.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSInteger weekOfYear = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```